# How to instantly display data after form submission using jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

I have a PHP form that uses jQuery/AJAX to submit data into a MySQL database table.  Currently, I have a message display saying " Done!" once the form is submitted, but would like the actual data to instantly display after it has been submitted.  I have a loop setup to display previously added messages in divs with the class name 'msg_container', and would like the new data to display in one of these divs after form submission.

What is the best way to do this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

index.php javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".button").click(function () {

            var user_id = $("textarea#uer_id").val();
            var msg = $("textarea#msg ").val();
            var dataString = 'user_id=' + user_id + '&msg=' + msg;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function () {
                    alert("Done!")
                }
            });
            return false
        });
    });
</script>
```

index.php query

```
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];

require_once('../../includes/connect.php');

$dbh = get_dbh($_SESSION['ORG_ID']);

$sth = $dbh->query ("SELECT *, user.last_name, user.first_name FROM msgs
                     INNER JOIN users
                     ON msgs.user_id = users.id
                     WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
                     ORDER BY timestamp");               

$row = $sth->fetch ();
```

index.php HTML

```
<div id="msgs">
    <?php while ($row = $sth->fetch ()) { ?>
    <div class="msg_container">
        <div class="left"><? echo $row['last_name'].', '.$row['first_name']; ?><br />
            <? $timestamp = date('m/d/Y g:i a', strtotime($row['timestamp'])); echo $timestamp; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="right"><? echo $row['msg']; ?></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <? } ?>
    <div class="add_note">
        <div class="left">Add Message</div>
        <div class="right">
            <form id="add_msg">
                <textarea id="msg" name="msg"></textarea>
                <input type='submit' class="button right-aligned" value='Submit' />
            </form>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add.php

```
<?php

require_once('../../includes/connect.php');

$dbh = get_dbh($_SESSION['ORG_ID']);

$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$msg= $_POST['msg'];

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strftime(gmmktime())); 
date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['TIME_ZONE']);

$sth = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO msgs (id, user_id, msg, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$data = array (NULL, $user_id, $msg, $timestamp);

$sth->execute ($data);

session_write_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just append the new message after the previous ones. Something like this:

```
 $.ajax({  
 type: "POST",  
 url: "add.php",  
 data: dataString,  
 success: function() {  
 alert ("Done!");
 $('#msgs').append('<div class="msg_container">' + 
 '<div class="left">' + lastNameVariable + ', ' + firstNameVariable + 
 '<br />' + timeStampVariable + 
 '</div><div class="right">' + msg + '</div>' +
 '<div class="clear"></div></div>');
 }  
 });
```

You will need to put the first name, last name, timestamp, etc. into variables (or do it a different way, like do an AJAX call to get the info - whatever you prefer). I didn't know what `user_id` is so I just thought I would let you fill in those variables.

This is just the basic idea of what you could do. If you have any questions, just ask.

I hope this helps.

---

### Edit:

If you created another page called "getname.php" or something like that (to get the first and last name) that would display "first name, last name" based on the user ID passed in the URL, that could work. In the URL it could have `?user_id=1234567` and then on that page, it would do a mysql_query and display the first and last name. This is what I would do:

***getname.php ↓***

```
<?
// ...
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND ...");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// ...
echo $row['last_name'] . ', ' . $row['first_name'];
// ...
?>
```

Of course you would do this the way you do your queries, but hopefully this helps you understand what I'm saying. Then, after you have that, you can do:

```
 $.ajax({  
 type: "POST",  
 url: "add.php",  
 data: dataString,  
 success: function() {  
 alert ("Done!");
 var firstAndLast = '';
 var theTime = 
 $.get('getname.php?user_id='+user_id, function(data) {
 firstAndLast = data;
 });
 $('#msgs').append('<div class="msg_container">' + 
 '<div class="left">' + firstAndLast // this will display: "first name, last name" because of getname.php
 + '<br />' + theTime + 
 '</div><div class="right">' + msg + '</div>' +
 '<div class="clear"></div></div>');
 }  
 });
```

As for the time, you could either [display it with JavaScript](http://momentjs.com/) (when they refresh it would show the time that was recorded by PHP) or do the same as you did for name.

Comment: This is very helpful; however, the lastNameVariable and firstNameVariable are based on a join query from the user_id.  Is there any easy way to requery before appending the data?

Comment: @Michael: I'm editing my answer with some extra stuff in it; I'll let you know when I'm done...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the jQuery ajax method [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/). This is a higher level version of `ajax`. You will send your request and the response will immediately be placed  into the preceding selector elements.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's just a quick idea to get you going. You need to return the data from the script you call with AJAX; a data that you would use to generate the DIV you want. You'll also need to change the ajax call to something like this:

```
$.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "add.php",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function(data) {
       console.log(data); //to see what's returned
       //use the data to generate content you want  
       alert ("Done!")
      }  
    });
```

Due to the structure of your data, it might be the best to send a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

In the success part add this code:

```
success: function(data){
$('#flash').css("display","block");;
setTimeout(function () {
$('#flash').slideUp();`enter code here`}, 2000);
}
```

In the HTML add this code:

```
<div id="flash" style="display:none;">Data Saved Successfully</div>
```